# Join arbitrary lines to output as one line

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I want to join the 3rd and 5th line of a file to the output of a script without trailing new lines.

Is it possible to implement this construction by using the code:

```
{
 echo 'Some text'
 echo 'Some text'
 echo -n 'Some text'
 cat text
 cat text
 echo -n 'Some text'
 echo 'Some text'
} > file
```

where I just need to add some option after cat?

Suppose that 3rd and 5th line of the file `text` are 3 and 5. After processing it must take the form:

```
 Some text 
 Some text
 Some text35Some text
 Some text
```

If I understand correctly, the implementation by sed commands is terrible in my case.

Comment: Please post input samples and expected output.

Comment: @don_crissti : I've added.

Comment: @don_crissti : I've completely edited my question.

Comment: So... you have an empty file and you want to add text in that empty file on third line ? Does that make sense to you ?

Comment: @don_crissti : no (please check changes in my question).

Comment: Hello! I added an update to your question. If you think I have missed something or you (for what ever reason) want to revert to original - please do so. It was a rather big edit ... :) - (If so: click the `edited nn mins ago` and select *rollback*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using sed

As I understand it, you have a file `text` which is something like:

```
$ cat text
1
2
3
4
5
```

And, you want to extract the 3rd and 5th lines and put them in the middle of some `echo` statements.  In that case, try:

```
$ {  echo 'Some text';  echo 'Some text';  echo -n 'Some text';  echo -n "$(sed -n 3p text)$(sed -n 5p text)";  echo 'Some text';  echo 'Some text'; } >file
$ cat file
Some text
Some text
Some text35Some text
Some text
```

#### Simplification

The above can be accomplished with a single `echo` command:

```
$ echo $'Some text\nSome text\nSome text'"$(sed -n 3p text)$(sed -n 5p text)"$'Some text\nSome text' >file
$ cat file
Some text
Some text
Some text35Some text
Some text
```

Or, as a single `printf` command:

```
$ printf 'Some text\nSome text\nSome text%s%sSome text\nSome text\n' "$(sed -n 3p text)" "$(sed -n 5p text)" >file
$ cat file
Some text
Some text
Some text35Some text
Some text
```

#### How the sed command works

The above uses sed commands such as:

```
sed -n 3p text
```

Here, `-n` is an option that tells sed not print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.  `3p` is a command that tells sed to print the third line.  Similarly, we use `5p` if we want to print the fifth line.

### Using awk

An awk solution (hat tip: Runium):

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
        printf "%s","Some text\nSome text\nSome text"
    }
    NR>5 {exit}
    NR==3 || NR==5 {printf "%s", $0}
    END{
        printf "%s","Some text\nSome text\n"
    }' text
```

Comment: Or with awk … `awk 'NR>5 {exit} NR==3 || NR==5 {printf "%s", $0}' text` …

Comment: @Runium Good point.  I updated the answer with an awk solution.